# GKE kubernetes delayed_job pod logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a deployment object with the following `rake jobs:work` command:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: staging-delayed-job-deployment
  namespace: staging
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        env: staging
        name: delayed-job
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: job
          image: gcr.io/ej-gc-dev/redacted:<%= ENV['IMAGE_TAG'] %>
          command: ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
          args: ["RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake jobs:work"]
```

When I run `kubectl logs` I get nothing. How do I get the `rake jobs:work` output to show in `kubectl logs` ? i.e if run directly in the pod it gives output like this:

```
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Job UpdateHubspotPersonaJob (id=67) RUNNING
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Job UpdateHubspotPersonaJob (id=67) COMPLETED after 0.4903
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Job Mailerjack.registration_created_user_welcome (id=68) RUNNING
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Job Mailerjack.registration_created_user_welcome (id=68) COMPLETED after 0.9115
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Job UpdateHubspotPersonaJob (id=69) RUNNING
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Job UpdateHubspotPersonaJob (id=69) COMPLETED after 0.1752
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Job Mailerjack.registration_created_user_welcome (id=70) RUNNING
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] Job Mailerjack.registration_created_user_welcome (id=70) COMPLETED after 0.4770
[Worker(host:staging-deployment-cc7dc559f-bswvr pid:2381)] 4 jobs processed at 1.7649 j/s, 0 failed
```

I want that to show up when I run `kubectl logs`

Comment: Hi, If you want to access the logs with `kubectl logs` then your pods needs to emit the logs to `stdout and stderr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add an initializer: `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` and set the worker's logger to stdout like so:

`Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

Comment: Hi already add `Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in `config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` but the delayed job is still not logging in Openshift pod?