# How do I run delayed_jobs in Kubernetes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, delayed-job

I can log into console from one of the pods (on kubernetes) and run this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

The jobs are run correctly doing that. However when the pods are deleted or restarted, the jobs stop running.

I also tried adding the command above in an initializer file (eg config/initializers/delayed_jobs_runner.rb), but I get a recursive loop when starting the app.

Another thing I tried to do is create a new file called `my-jobs.yaml` with this

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: job
        image: gcr.io/test-app-123/somename:latest
        command: ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
        args: ["RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake jobs:work"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

I then do `kubectl apply -f my-jobs.yaml`, but the jobs aren't running.

Any idea how to run delayed_jobs correctly in kubernetes?

EDIT: Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/ruby

# Install 2.5.1 if not already preinstalled by the base image
RUN cd /rbenv/plugins/ruby-build && \
    git pull && \
    rbenv install -s 2.5.1 && \
    rbenv global 2.5.1 && \
    gem install -q --no-rdoc --no-ri bundler 
    # --version 1.11.2

ENV RBENV_VERSION 2.5.1

# Copy the application files.
COPY . /app/

# Install required gems.
RUN bundle install --deployment && rbenv rehash

# Set environment variables.
ENV RACK_ENV=production \
    RAILS_ENV=production \
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true

# Run asset pipeline.
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile


CMD ["setup.sh"]


# Reset entrypoint to override base image.
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]




################### setup.sh ############################
cd /app && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job -n 2 start
bundle exec foreman start --formation "$FORMATION"
#########################################################
```

Comment: This is more of a suggestion, have you tried looking into this [gem](https://github.com/Shopify/kubernetes-deploy). It provides methods, to run jobs, tasks etc exclusively.

Comment: Your job fails or doesn't start at all? What do your logs/events show?

Comment: Can you please try: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826651/gke-kubernetes-delayed-job-pod-logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826651/gke-kubernetes-delayed-job-pod-logs)

Comment: Nicola, the job starts fine. It's just that I have to manually start the delayed_jobs script every time I create/delete/recreate new pods on kubernetes. I have to log into one of the pod's shell and run a "RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start" in the console. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: tekuri, I tried that with the my-jobs.yaml above, but the jobs aren't starting unfortunately.

Comment: Kedarnag, thanks for your suggestion. The link does seem overwhelming for me, but I'll read into it more.

Comment: This command works for me from my local terminal: kubectl exec POD_NAME -- bash -c 'cd /app && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job -n 2 start'. Maybe a way to automate this is just to run this command after every kubernetes deployment. I'm not sure if that's the recommended way though (especially if the associated pod is deleted).

Comment: Have you considered putting this line in you docker image itself? RUN [...]? Or are there any reasons you want to avoid that? For me it sounds as this has to be executed after every start of a container. I would it place there.

Comment: Hi Christoph. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding the worker to the RUN command in the Dockerfile, but the jobs still aren't executed. I added my Dockerfile above. It seems like jobs are only executed if I run the worker directly on an existing pod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running multiple processes in one docker container is problematic as you cannot easily observe lifetime of particular process - every container need one process which is "main" and when it exit, container also exit.

As looking on Github (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#user-content-running-jobs) I would strongly suggest to change a little your starting command to run it in foreground because now when you are starting Kubernetes job with daemons 
 - job is ending immediately as docker container lifetime is directly related to "main" foreground process lifetime so when you run only background process your main process exit immediately and your container too.

Change your command to:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run
```

What start worker in foreground so your Kubernetes Job won't exit. Please note also that Kubernetes Jobs are not intended to such infinitive tasks (job should has start and end) so I would suggest to use [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) for that

Comment: Wow Jakub! It works! I changed "cd /app && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job -n 2 start" in my Dockerfile setup.sh to "cd /app && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job run". However, when I change it back to the previous command (without the "run" delayed_jobs command), the delayed_jobs still run after deployment. Is that expected? I'm still testing it but this looks very promising. Thank you so much Jakub!

Comment: If you run them as Kubernetes Jobs please note that they are Immutable what means that you cannot changes theirs commands after start. You need to kill particular Job, delete and create once again.

Comment: Good stuff Jakub. Appreciate your great help on this. I learned so many things about Kubernetes from you. Thank you so much!! Rewarding you the bounty now :)

Comment: Thank you for bounty and good luck in your adventure in containers world :)!

Comment: Rails kinda needs to run multiple processes in many cases to be efficient. I am looking for a way to do this well. We have it running, and we are putting a tail command to tail the logs as the foreground. But the issue we have is that it doesn't terminate if the job workers crash for some reason, like the cloud database gets restarted or something. We run 6 puma servers in our rails web pods, and we have a health check for that. so I am working on a health check for the worker container as well. Admittedly an imperfect solution. But much more efficient than running one worker.

Comment: @nroose There's a better way in kuberenetes... you can run a pod with multiple containers.  These share access to a filesystem, etc. but run in separate docker images.

Comment: @PatrickNarkinsky Not really sure how that applies in this instance. We have changed a lot since 2019. We do run 3 workers in one container. And we have a script in the foreground that runs and re-runs a tail command to output the logs. Seems to work well these days.

Answer (score 2):

Now I am doing this:

```
this_pid=$$
(while [[ $(ps -ef | grep delayed_job | grep -v -e grep -e tail | head -c1 | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]; do sleep 10; done; kill -- -$this_pid) &
```

after starting multiple workers. And after this I `tail -f` the logs so that those go to the standard output of the container. I am quite crazy, so I am also running logrotate to keep the logs in check. The rails environment is pretty big anyway, so the container needs to be pretty big, and we need to be able to run many jobs and I don't want many pods running to do so. This seems to be efficient and will stop and restart if the workers die for some reason.